# C fifo linked list char push

Tags: c, linked-list, fifo

I'm currently trying to understand fifo linked list and found example here [Example](http://www.cprogramto.com/queue-using-linked-list-in-c/) , and I'm trying to input char instead of `int`

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct Node
 {
        char Data;
        struct Node* next;
 }*rear, *front;

void delQueue()
{
       struct Node *temp, *var=rear;
      if(var==rear)
      {
             rear = rear->next;
             free(var);
      }
      else
      printf("\nQueue Empty");
}

void push(char *value)
{
     struct Node *temp;
     temp=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
     temp->Data=value;
     if (front == NULL)
     {
           front=temp;
           front->next=NULL;
           rear=front;
     }
     else
     {
           front->next=temp;
           front=temp;
           front->next=NULL;
     }
}

void display()
{
     struct Node *var=rear;
     if(var!=NULL)
     {
           printf("\nElements are as:  ");
           while(var!=NULL)
           {
                printf("\t%d",var->Data);
                var=var->next;
           }
     printf("\n");
     }
     else
     printf("\nQueue is Empty");
}

int main()
{
     int i=0;
     char ch;
     front=NULL;
     printf(" \n1. Push to Queue");
     printf(" \n2. Pop from Queue");
     printf(" \n3. Display Data of Queue");
     printf(" \n4. Exit\n");
     while(1)
     {
          printf(" \nChoose Option: ");
          //scanf("%d",&i);
          ch = getchar();
          switch(ch)
          {
                case '+':
                {
                     char value[20];
                     printf("\nEnter a valueber to push into Queue : ");
                     scanf("%s", value);
                     push(value);
                     printf("%s",value);
                     display();
                     break;
                }
                case '-':
                {
                     delQueue();
                     display();
                     break;
                }
                case '*':
                {
                     display();
                     break;
                }
                case '$':
                {
                     exit(0);
                }
                default:
                {
                     printf("\nwrong choice for operation");
                }
          }
     }
}
```

I can't understand this warning on line 26: *warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast*

I can input text, for example: "Hello world", but when I want to display it, it is showed as "-9".
I am really confused.

Comment: Dont post a link to your code. Paste it directly into your question and then highlight it and press `cntrl+k`

Comment: The warning means what it says: a pointer is being coerced into an integer or numeric type (*e.g.*, `char`) for some reason without being explicitly type casted. You need to look at the code at that line (I didn't look carefully at it - the code you link to has no line numbers and I didn't feel like counting them), and determine if that's done intentionally or is in error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is defined as `char`, but your assigning a `char *` (`char` pointer) to it. That creates the warning, and surely won't work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for that! For what ever reason did not notice that!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Node` struct, the value is of type `char`, but you're assigning a `char*` to it instead. This is why you get the warning, and why printing things doesn't come out right.